# Infer generic subtype in dynamic record

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a configuration management class that maps keys with some resolution strategies.  In doing so, I'd like to have an accessor function that retrieves the value, and the correct type from the dynamic map.

```js
type ParameterDescription<T> = {
  default: T;
};

type ParameterDictionary = Record<
  string,
  ParameterDescription<string | number | boolean>
>;

type ParameterSubType<T> = T extends ParameterDescription<infer U> ? U : never;

const config: ParameterDictionary = {
  foo: { default: "test" },
  bar: { default: 1 },
  baz: { default: true },
};

function get<T extends ParameterDictionary, K extends keyof T>(config: T, key: K): ParameterSubType<T[K]>;
function get<T extends ParameterDictionary>(config: T, key: string): undefined {
  return config[key].default || undefined;
}

const a = get(config, "foo"); // type is string
const b = get(config, "bar"); // type is number
const c = get(config, "baz"); // type is boolean
const d = get(config, "boz"); // type is undefined
```

Is something like this possible?  I'd like to avoid having to declare an interface that explicitly lists the key types; ie:

```js
interface {
  foo: ParameterDescription<string>
  bar: ParameterDescription<number>
}
```

Comment: Mostly all you need to do is let the compiler infer the type of `config` instead of annotating it as a wide type that forgets its structure.  Then I suppose you want to allow `key` not to be a known key of `config` and assume the value is `undefined` (an unsound assumption but probably reasonable).  The required changes are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAgQPw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I think that accomplishes what I'm after.  I'm having trouble understanding why my solution didn't work and what the critical differences are.

Comment: Ah, I see that you removed the type hint of ParameterDictionary from config.  I guess this is a case of being too verbose in my typing.

Comment: It's not a "hint", it's an annotation.  And if you annotate a variable with a (non-union) type, then that's the type the compiler will use for it, not some more specific type of the initializer.  I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the `config` variable to be of type `ParameterDictionary` like

```
const config: ParameterDictionary = {
  foo: { default: "test" },
  bar: { default: 1 },
  baz: { default: true },
}
```

but by doing that you are explicitly throwing away any more specific information the compiler might have had from the [object literal initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).  Instead you should probably just let the compiler *infer* its type:

```
const config = {
  foo: { default: "test" },
  bar: { default: 1 },
  baz: { default: true },
};
```

Or, if you really want to see some kind of warning if `config` fails to be a `ParameterDictionary`, you could use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) on the initializer:

```
const config = {
  foo: { default: "test" },
  bar: { default: 1 },
  baz: { default: true },
} satisfies ParameterDictionary;
```

Once you do that, the compiler will know that `config.foo.default` is a `string`, etc.

---

Then you need to modify the call signature of `get()` to allow `key` to be any property key and not just known keys of `config`.  Perhaps like this:

```
function get<T extends ParameterDictionary, K extends PropertyKey>(
  config: T, key: K
): K extends keyof T ? T[K]["default"] : undefined;

function get(config: ParameterDictionary, key: string) {
  return config[key]?.default; // <-- note that this fixes your broken impl
}
```

Here the return type of `get()` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks if `K` (the type of `key`) is known to be a key of `T` (the type of `config`).  If so, you get the type of the `default` property of `T[K]`.  If not, you get `undefined`.  This gives you the desired behavior:

```
const a = get(config, "foo"); // const a: string
const b = get(config, "bar"); // const b: number
const c = get(config, "baz"); // const c: boolean
const d = get(config, "boz"); // const d: undefined
```

(Note that I had to fix the implementation so that the last would be `undefined` at runtime and not a `TypeError`)

---

So that's the answer to the question as asked. There's a caveat here: TypeScript object types are not "sealed"; just because a type doesn't mention a key, doesn't mean there isn't such a key present on a value of that type.  So technically returning `undefined` when a key isn't known to exist might not be correct.  For example:

```
const config2 = {
  foo: { default: "test" },
  bar: { default: 1 },
  baz: { default: true },
  oops: { default: "oops" }
} satisfies ParameterDictionary; // okay

const oops: typeof config = config2; // okay
const e = get(oops, "oops");
// const e: undefined
console.log(e); // "oops" <-- not undefined
```

That's pretty unlikely, since it relies on aliasing and widening, but you might want to be aware.  The "safe" way to implement `get()` is either to have the return value be `unknown` instead of `undefined`, or to make the compiler reject any keys that aren't known.  But that's digressing from the question, so I'll stop here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-UsMcn426fVmLWGS4Z4imMwGcTAOE304d+5wDRNMnmi2W-xUbglfO27bIiLgIH7Qagp+34AghMHeT6MKQ7xl6L5vrWwbQMw1qnlGp5xmwCYDhAXbspyXC1lWepCGQdiQhAbYJtUCFAA)

Comment: It is possible to replicate this pattern in a class where the dictionary is a member of the class?  I tried to implement that and I'm getting the original problem.

Comment: I was able to get it working using [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK3RDW) but I feel like that may be a sloppy implementation?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2k3rN) perhaps?

Comment: One final question on this pattern.  I'm now trying to allow the get function to accept an array of keys or strings, and return a record of the known type or unknown.  I made some changes to the class, including a new ParameterSubType type that infers the type, and that is working correctly.  However, I can't seem to get the array overload signature to type the response correctly.  Any thoughts on [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEgB4m)?  I can create a new question if you think that is best.  Thank you!

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3X3m) perhaps?  Note that followup questions in comments aren't really appropriate for SO.  If you have further questions please do open a new question.  Good luck!